# major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest major version supported by this compiler. Android studio

Tags: java, android

I got a warning while I compile it tells me :

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac
warning: C:\Users\bleuc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.1\core-lambda- 
stubs.jar(java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.class): major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest 
major version supported by this compiler.
It is recommended that the compiler be upgraded.
C:\Users\bleuc\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\30.0.1\core-lambda- 
stubs.jar(java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.class): major version 53 is newer than 52, the highest 
major version supported by this compiler.
```

1 warning

How can I resolve this? I'm using android studio.

In my module:app

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

I know 53 is java 9 so I tried to pout 1_9 but it shows me so much errors.

Up! I don't know how to correct this on Android studio

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, i updated my buildToolsVersion in `build.gradle` (app level, e.g. Module: YourApp.app) "30.0.2" and the warning disapeard.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: For those, who (like me) don't know, what is `buildToolsVersion` - it is property defined in `build.gradle` file in the `app` directory at the very top. Android Studio even nicely highlights it to notify, that the value can be increased and with "Show Context Actions" it suggests to replace it with the latest available.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take Windows as an example, if your OS's JRE is Java 8 (52), while your program is complied in Java 14 (58), you will face a similar error. However, if you specify the program to run with JDK 14 binary, it will run normally.

In short, check what your system default JRE is, if it's older than the one you use to compile, you will have this error. Note that you might not face any issue in IDE since you set your IDE to use newer version of JRE.

Make sure to properly associate the .jar file with the supported JRE, so it will you the correct JRE to run the executable.

Comment: Why it doesn't update itself.... My jdk is in android folder what android want to me to do again U_U

Comment: You cannot automatically update major revision of Java since it involves the change in a language or compiler itself, so it can potentially cause a huge problem to the deployment process. However, you can receive cumulative update like Java8_u260 to Java8_u261. Major revision must be updated manually. If my answer can solve your problem, please mark it as accepted (a check mark on the left of my answer), I appreciate.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to do it

Comment: I think I start to understand. So I need to install java 9 (53)??

Comment: Right, or any newer version. Another approach is recompile your project using Java 8, and you won't need to install a new JDK, this is only possible assuming you don't use any Java 9 feature.